# Lumia 925 screen goes blank after dialing a number

Tags: 8.1, lumia-925, display

The screen on my Lumia 925 goes blank for a couple of minutes just after dialing a phone number, then gets back to normal. While this is happening, I can press the power off button and the screen will show momentarily before going blank again. It will stay blank until the call has ended or the person I'm calling hangs up.

Please advise on possible error. Would it help to do a factory reset?

Answer (score 6):

Check so there is nothing that covers the proximity sensor. The purpose is to blank the screen when you hold the phone to your ear while in a call.
My dad had the exact same problem and he put a small piece of tape over the sensor (since the SIM card hatch didn't stay in place). Ones I removed the tape it worked great.